# og:title doesn't correpond with the one I set

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have a question regarding the meta property in php.
I have set
 
and I have a list of products that need to be displayed on the first page. Whwn I click the first product and click the like button the title that appears is different from the one I set, but when I click the other products and then click like I get the correct title. I tried clearing the cache but it didn't work and I tried verifying the link using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and here it teels me that the title is the one I set. 
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or what might be the problem? Or maybe you have a soultion for this. :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the page which is being changed and liked, it's hard to know if I am answering your question, but the information may be useful to you anyway.

The issue may be with how many likes have already added up for the page.

> Note that og:title and og:type are only editable initially - after
>   your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

This has happened to me before. The easy fix/workaround I found was this: I had been appending a query string to the page URL for tracking some stats. That URL with the query string had over 50 likes. Once I changed the query string, or left it off, the page had a different amount of likes. So when I used the Facebook linter/debugger, I used the new URL and it picked up my og:title and description change.

Are you able to post a link to the page you are having this issue with?

Comment: [link]http://beyoutrend.ro/new/index.php/product/84/dasdadsa/?cat=12&lang=en this is the product that tends to act different. I don't know if you will be able to access it because the site is not yet launched. I was doing only tests to see how it works my like button. And only for one product it does like this and I don't have so many likes. :P

Comment: I noticed for the og:url you have this url: http://beyoutrend.ro/new/index.php/product/84/dasdadsa/ so instead of using the url with the query string in the debugger, I entered this one. Went back to the page and liked, it seems to have fixed the title issue. this gets back to Facebook recognizing these as two separate urls because of the query string on one. As far as it is concerned the one with the query string could be a completely different page. You may want to do a google search for rel="canonical" to learn more about duplicate content issues with multiple urls.

Comment: rel="canonical" really did the trick....thank you very much for your help wylander....I owe you one:P

Comment: no problem, glad to have answered your question. If you don't mind, can you 'accept' my answer here? Thanks! :) http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask